# How to write multi-line Python script block in GitLab pipeline using a YAML file

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, codeblocks, gitlab-ci.yml

The following script block works perfectly for me when run as a simple Python script from VSCode.

```
  d = {'A':123, 'B':456, 'C':789, 'D':222}

  for key, value in d.items():

      print(f'{key} {value}')
```

However, I'm desperate to replicate this in a GitLab pipeline and considered whether something along the lines of what I have depicted below, could do the trick in my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

So far, all attempts have proved unsuccessful. Any ideas or suggestions on how I can get this to work, or even an alternative approach that would equally work? My actual intended implementation will be for a slightly more extensive block of code, but any working solution proposed here would be the perfect building block to get that up and running for sure.

```
default:
  image:
    name: python:latest
    entrypoint: [""]

  before_script:
    - python -m pip install --upgrade pip
  
stages:
  - test_1


variables:
  OUTPUTFILE: 'testoutput.txt'


test_multiline_script_block:
  stage: test_1
  image:
    name: python:latest
  script:
    - |
      d = {'A':123, 'B':456, 'C':789, 'D':222}

      for key, value in d.items():
      
          print(f'{key} {value}')
```

NB: So, just for the sake of clarity, let me perhaps elaborate a bit on what I'm seeking to implement.

Using a loop function, I want to be able to iterate through a key-value pair list and for each key/value pair obtained, I'll pass them into a python script as two arguments, e.g. `python3 myscript.py $key $value`. This python script is executed from my .gitlab-ci.yml file.

My key-value pair list could be stored in an external file, e.g.
kv_list.txt, be initialised as a variable in my .gitlab-ci.yml file, or
be stored in any other format for that matter. The key thing is that I should be able to read the list and pass each key/value pair into my python
script.

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format is XML based. Please don't confuse that with a file containing a YAML document (for which the recommended extension has been `.yaml` since at least Sep 2006)

Comment: why not just save the file as `run.py` or something and run it within the job

Comment: Anthon, not sure I grasp your point in relation to the query raised and how is this query relevant with the YML format or the .yaml extension you're referencing??

Comment: Sibtain, unfortunately my task isn't as simple as executing a python script from my .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline file. Yes, the script you're suggesting will run successfully if run independently, but what I'm seeking to do is to inject some key-value pair data resulting from that script execution, back into my .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline file to be consumed by some other command(s).